# Limit youtube full screen mode to window in firefox using qtile

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, firefox

I'm wondering if there's a way to limit the full screen mode in youtube to just the window that Firefox already takes up. I know that Firefox has the picture in picture mode that creates a floating window, but that seems like a pretty hacky way of doing it. I'd like be able to just click full screen and have the full screen constrained to that window. It would also be nice to have it on a key toggle so that I could have the video take up the whole screen sometimes.I'm using Qtile as my window manager.

Comment: Not a 'native' solution, but you could use an extension like this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/windowed/

Comment: Not really the solution I was hoping for, but it's something that can work until I figure out a way to do it without a Firefox extension. Thanks.

Comment: The question is contradictory. In essence, "How can I get _fullscreen_ **without** fullscreen?" It sounds like what you want is to make the video play in the full size of the Firefox window, instead of fullscreen _or_ in a player that only displays on part of the page, correct? (Edit your question to clarify, so that others on the site will see it and understand... do not simply reply in comments which they may not read...)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting `auto_fullscreen = False` in your config. Set a key binding for manually going full screen using `lazy.window.toggle_fullscreen()` and you'll be good to go. Now, whenever you double click on a video or press <kbd>f</kbd>, it will only take up the window size unless you manually switch to fullscreen mode with your keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Another hack would be to  change the YouTube URL from

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1De0Ha5h
```

to

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/V1De0Ha5h
```

This would leave you with the video maximized within the current tab + the tab bar and the toolbar on top which you can remove by other means if you want.